# I got a mongodb collection which items has create_time and delete_time field.I want a Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I want a Aggregation.(or does aggregation can solve my question?)

#### *for example:*

There is a timestamp, if one item's create_time less than the timestamp and the delete_time large than the timestamp, it count 1, loop all items,  i can get the count in the timestamp, a series of count is what i needed.

This process too slow in my app.

Can mongodb aggregation help me? thanks

Comment: can you explain a bit more on _series of count is what i needed_ you can do aggregation if you want the output of aggregations as {count:xxx,timeStamp:ISODate(xxxxxxxx)}

Comment: @kryshna hi,i not sure, but i can explain what i was done on my app, i pick the nearest 30 days, i count erery day which match i said on question above, then i got 30time and 30 digit,i made them a curve graph,so i can see the tendency of these items's increase, i alse need count the nearest 15 weeks, 6 months, does it help?

Comment: @kryshna yes, {count:xxx,timeStamp:ISODate(xxxxxxxx)} is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, this is the query

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $project:{cmp:{$and: [{$lt:["$create_time",ISODate("2016-04-24T13:10:09.518Z")]}, {$gt:["$delete_time",ISODate("2016-04-25T13:10:09.518Z")]}] } } },{$match:{cmp:true}},{$group:{_id:"$cmp",count:{$sum:1}}}])
```

This one will basically gives output as `{ "_id" : true, "count" : 2 }`.
Where count is number of documents satisfying the condition you specified. Replace ISODate("xxxx") with your ISO Date.
And if you also want number of documents that don't satisfy your query remove the match object in the pipeline.